# How was this integral with functions as limits solved?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

How was this integral solved ?

$$\displaystyle \frac d{dy}\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)}f(x,y)dx$$ $$=\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)}\frac \partial{\partial y} f(x,y)dx+f(h(y),y)\frac{dh(y)}{dy}-f(g(y),y)\frac{dg(y)}{dy}$$

I can see intiutively  where $+f(h(y),y)\frac{dh(y)}{dy}-f(g(y),y)\frac{dg(y)}{dy}$ come from but not the other term $\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)}\frac \partial{\partial y} f(x,y)dx$.

I do not see which was first calculated, the integral and the the derivative or was first the derivative and then the integral?

Comment: Google helps. It shows https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule, which has proofs.

Comment: @MPW oh I didn't know it have a name, my book does not mention the name Leibniz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac d{dy}\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)}f(x,y)dx==\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)}\frac \partial{\partial y} f(x,y)dx+f(h(y),y)\frac{dh(y)}{dy}-f(g(y),y)\frac{dg(y)}{dy}$

The above expression is nothing but "Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign)".

> **Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign):**
>
> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function of $x$ and $t$ such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a(x) ≤ t ≤ b(x)$, and $ x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$,
> $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt\right)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,t) dt +f( x, b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f( x, a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}$$

You can find the proof from the following links:

$1.$ http://sgpwe.izt.uam.mx/files/users/uami/jdf/proyectos/Derivar_inetegral.pdf

$2.$ [Leibniz rule derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840503/leibniz-rule-derivation)

$3.$ [http://www.econ.yale.edu/~pah29/409web/leibniz.pdf](http://www.econ.yale.edu/%7Epah29/409web/leibniz.pdf)