# Calculating $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{0}^{x} e^{(kt)} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

It sounds like such a simple thing to do and yet i'm stuck. I appreciate any help or guidance.

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{0}^{x} e^{(kt)} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t $$

I tried this method:
$$\int_{0}^{x} e^{(kt)} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t =F(x)-F(0)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(F(x)-F(0)\right) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (F(x)) \overset{?}{=} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(\int e^{(kx)} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x\right)=  e^{(kx)} f(x)$$
But I'm not sure if the one but last step is "ok" to do. I'm looking for a better way to justify this.

Comment: It looks like a straight forward application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. (Your final answer is correct.)

Comment: You might point out that $F(0)$ will be a constant, which is why it disappears under differentiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the fundamental theorem of calculus, if $g:[0,x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the function $F:[0,x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$F(x):=\int_0^xg(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ is differentiable on $(0,x),$ and $F'=f$ on $(0,x).$ In this case, you have $g(t)=e^{kt}f(t),$ hence $F'(x)=e^{kx}f(x).$

Answer (score 1):

A general version of differentiating an integral is described by [Leibniz's integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). There are multiple proofs of this rule that can be found in the article itself.

Here's an [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840503/leibniz-rule-derivation) that also talks about the proof.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot!